# Cannot set property 'class' of undefined

Tags: javascript, css, xpages, client-side

I'm certain I'm doing something stupid, or missing something silly but I get the follow 2 error messages, from client side onClick of a button:

> Cannot set property 'class' of undefined
>
> Cannot set property 'scrollTop' of null

All I'm trying to do is style an inputTextArea, and then scroll to the top of a scrollable content div that I have.

```
    document.getElementById(x$("#{id:obj1Error}").Attributes["class"] = "has-error");
    var myDiv = document.getElementById(x$("#{id:contentWhiteBackground}"));
    myDiv.scrollTop = 0;
```

Any pointers appreciated. Cheers

UPDATE:

Client code on button:

```
// Make sure user has entered content into the first objective at minimum
var objcolparent = document.getElementById("ObjColOuter").children[0];
var objValue = objcolparent.getElementsByTagName("TEXTAREA")[0].value;

if(objValue ==""){
var o = {};
o.title = "Validation Failed";
o.body = "You must enter at least one objective before submitting";
o.alertIcon = "fa-thumbs-down fa-lg";
o.alertType = "danger";

var myDiv = document.getElementById("#{id:contentWhiteBackground}");
//document.getElementById("#{id:obj1Error}").className = "has-error";
myDiv.scrollTop = 0;
bootAlert.show('alertServer',JSON.stringify(o));
return false;
}

if(confirm("Are you sure you want to submit your objectives?")){
return true;
}else{
return false;
}
```

Code on xpage, which contains the obj1Error div:

```
<xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="100"
                            value="#{viewScope.fields}" var="fieldName">

                            <xp:text escape="true"
                                id="computedField4" styleClass="h5">


                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"Objective "+@RightBack(fieldName, 16)}]]></xp:this.value>
                            </xp:text>
                            <br />
                            <xp:div id="obj1Error">

                                <xp:text escape="true"
                                    id="computedField1" styleClass="h6">



                                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"Details"}]]></xp:this.value>
                                </xp:text>
                                <xp:inputTextarea
                                    id="inputTextarea1" style="height:100px;resize:none;"
                                    showReadonlyAsDisabled="true">
                                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{document1[fieldName]}]]></xp:this.value>
                                    <xp:this.disabled><![CDATA[#{javascript:try{

var strStatus:string = document1.getItemValueString("status"); 
var booDisabled:boolean = true;

if(strStatus == "New" || strStatus == "Draft" || strStatus == "Returned") {
booDisabled = false;
}

return booDisabled;

}catch(e){
writeToLog("Error - ccObjectives disable objective details: " + e);
}}]]></xp:this.disabled>

                                </xp:inputTextarea>
                            </xp:div>
                            <br />
                        </xp:repeat>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what xpages are but by the look of this you are trying to mix javascript and jquery. My guess would be that you either do: `document.getElementById("#{id:obj1Error}")` or `x$("#{id:obj1Error}")`

Comment: Is the "obj1Error" control rendered? Please show your complete button and obj1Error control code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to write

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("#{id:contentWhiteBackground}");
```

to get the DOM element.

To set an element's class(es) you have to write:

```
document.getElementById("#{id:obj1Error}").className = "has-error";
```

Comment: The scrollTop works so thanks. Pretty sure I tried that before and it didn't work which is why I then used the selector. However in regards the styling, I get the same error as trying the dojo approach that Georg suggested: I get: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null.

Comment: That means that the element with the given ID could not be found, either because the element is not present, or the ID is empty. To check if the XPages-ID is resolved properly you could temporarily output the ID via `alert("#{id:obj1Error}");`. If an empty string is returned, then the problem lies in your XPages markup and not the CSJS.

Comment: It is there, I can see if in firebug, and using the alert returns view:_id1:_id2:_id43:repeat1:obj1Error. I'll edit my question with code formatting

Comment: Did you output the alert in the same routine as the one where you set the className? Did you verify that the element you refer to has the EXACT same ID as is shown in the alert?

Comment: Slight difference.... alert returns view:_id1:_id2:_id43:repeat1:obj1Error  .........firebug returns view:_id1:_id2:_id43:repeat1:0:obj1Error......... so theres a 0 added after the repeat... Why is that?

Comment: The "0" is added because it's the iteration index within the repeat control. The problem is that your button seems to be outside of the repeat control. It has to be on the inside in order for `"#{id:obj1Error}"` to return the correct ID for the obj1Error element in each repeat entry.

Comment: If it suffices to have a single element for outputting any errors from the repeat entries then just move obj1Error out of the repeat control

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, I've moved the Div outside the repeat and it works. Only problem is it now styles all the fields within the repeat rather than just the one I wanted, but I'm sure I can figure that out. Thanks

Comment: I thought that now both the obj1Error element as well as the button are outside of the repeat control. To me there is no reason why styling that one element should change the styles of elements within the repeat, unless you have some styling code within that control.

Comment: Sorry, should have elaborated... The div istarts outside the repeat, but ends after the repeat, as the field I want to style is within the repeat

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to work with the [dojo toolkit](https://dojotoolkit.org/) in xpages instead of native javascript:

```
dojo.addClass('#{id:obj1Error}','has-error');
var myDiv = dojo.byId('#{id:contentWhiteBackground}');
myDiv.scrollTop = 0;
```

Comment: I get: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of null